# TCP nonblock connect failed with getsockopt OptValue 113 Please suggest

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I have created a sample TCP connect function. This uses non-blocking socket with timeout. The code is working fine in our lab but in some network TCP connect fails with error
115 which means EINPROGRESS. After debug found `getsockopt()` set the iValopt to 113
and we check `optvalue` is equal to zero, if not return failure.

OS: LINUX Suse10

My questions are:

1. Is the code pasted here right?
2. Why `getsockopt()` Opt value is set to 113 and errno set to 115?

Also I notice below.

- Client has multiple IP:  174.66.45.22, 58.68.445.112
- Server has multiple IP:  174.88.69.33, 58.46.22.33
- If I set Bind address to 174.66.45.22 and connect to 174.88.69.33 is always success.
- If I set Bind address to 174.66.45.22 and connect to 58.46.22.33 will fail.
- But if I just set Bind address to 58.68.445.112 in first run and in second run I change Bind address to 174.66.45.22 then connect to 58.46.22.33 is Success!

Can you explain why?

The exact code I have pasted here

```
int tcp_sockconnect_linux(int iSocket, const struct sockaddr* pstSockAddr, unsigned int uiSockAddrLen, unsigned int uiConnectionTimeout)
{
    int iRet  = 0;
    //int iValopt = 0;
    int iLength = 0; 
    struct timeval stTv; 
    fd_set write_fds;

    (void)fcntl((int)(long)iSocket, F_SETFL,  O_NONBLOCK);

    iRet = connect((int)(long)iSocket, (struct sockaddr*) pstSockAddr, uiSockAddrLen); 

    if (iRet < 0)
    { 
        if (errno == EINPROGRESS) 
        { 
            stTv.tv_sec = uiConnectionTimeout; 
            stTv.tv_usec = 0; 
            FD_ZERO(&write_fds); 
            FD_SET((int)(long)iSocket, &write_fds); 

            if (0 < select(((int)(long)(iSocket)) + 1,NULL, &write_fds, NULL, &stTv))
            { 
                iLength = sizeof(int); 

                if (0 > getsockopt((int)(long)iSocket, SOL_SOCKET,SO_ERROR, (void*)(&iValopt), &iLength))
                {
                return -1;
                }

                if (0 != iValopt)
                { 
                return -1;
                }

                return 2;
            } 
            else
            { 
            return -1; 
            } 
        } 
        else
        { 
        return -1; 
        } 
    } 

    return 2;
}


int create_socket(void) 
{
    int iRet, sock_sd; 
    struct sockaddr_in saServer;
    struct sockaddr_in saLocal;     

#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if(WSAStartup(0x101, &wsaData)) 
    {
        printf("Unable to initialize WinSock library.\n");
    }
#endif

    memset (&saLocal,'\0', sizeof(saLocal));  
    saLocal.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    saLocal.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(strBindAddr);
    saLocal.sin_port        = htons(0);

    sock_sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    memset (&saServer,'\0', sizeof(saServer));  
    saServer.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    saServer.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (strServerIP); 
    saServer.sin_port        = htons(uiServerPort);  

    iRet = bind((unsigned int)sock_sd,(struct sockaddr*) &saLocal,sizeof(saLocal));
#ifdef WIN32
    if (iRet ==  SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nTCP Bind Failed to LocalIP %s\n",strBindAddr);
    }
#else
    if (-1 == iRet)
    {
        printf("\nTCP Bind Failed to LocalIP %s\n",strBindAddr);
    }
#endif



#ifdef WIN32
    iRet = tcp_sockconnect_win(sock_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &saServer,sizeof(saServer),uiConnectionTimeOut); 
    if (iRet ==  SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nTCP Socket Connect Failed with  ErrorNo = %d  iValopt = %d  LineNo = %d \n",WSAGetLastError(),iValopt,iLineNo);
    }
    else if (2 == iRet)
    {
        printf("\nTCP Socket Connect Success \n");
    }
#else
    iRet = tcp_sockconnect_linux(sock_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &saServer,sizeof(saServer),uiConnectionTimeOut);
    if(-1 == iRet)
    {
        printf("\nTCP Socket Connect Failed with  ErrorNo = %d   iValopt = %d  LineNo = %d\n",errno,iValopt,iLineNo);
    }
    else if (2 == iRet)

    {
        printf("\nTCP Socket Connect Success %d\n",iLineNo);
    }

#endif


#ifdef WIN32
    closesocket (sock_sd);
#else
    close(sock_sd);
#endif

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    int iRet = 0;

    printf ("Enter the Bind Address (Local IP): ");
    scanf("%s" ,&strBindAddr);

    printf ("\nEnter the IP Address of Server : ");
    scanf("%s" ,&strServerIP);

    printf ("\nEnter the PORT Number of Server : ");
    scanf("%d" ,&uiServerPort);

    printf ("\nEnter the Connection timeout in Seconds : ");
    scanf("%d", &uiConnectionTimeOut);

    iRet = create_socket();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it without the `bind()` step. You don't need that in most circumstances. And after the `select()` returns with the socket writable, you have to call `connect()` again.

Comment: What's the `(int)(long)` cast for?

Comment: errno is the result of the last syscall, while the value returned by SO_ERROR is the "pending socket error": the error on this network thing. These are supposed to be different.

Comment: @EJP: what is the connect() needed for? According to connect(2) manpage just the selects completion for writing is enough...

Comment: @fork0 Last time I programmed BSD sockets was 20 years ago before `SO_ERROR` existed. That was the technique recommended at the time. These days I guess you would look at `SO_ERROR` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Few days back even I was facing the same kinda issue. Below is how I could solve.

In the W.R. Stevens book, *UNIX® Network Programming Volume 1, Third Edition: The Sockets Networking API* - 16.4 Non-blocking connect: Daytime Client, which talks about the non compatibility of various connects, we can get some answers :

> As we said earlier, there are portability problems with various socket implementations and nonblocking connects. First, it is possible for a connection to complete and for data to arrive from a peer before select is called. In this case, the socket will be both readable and writable on success, the same as if the connection had failed. Our code in Figure 16.11 handles this scenario by calling `getsockopt` and checking the pending error for the socket.
>
> Next is determining whether the connection completed successfully or not, if we cannot assume that writability is the only way success is returned. Various solutions have been posted to Usenet. These would replace our call to `getsockopt` in Figure 16.11.
>
> 1. Call `getpeername` instead of `getsockopt`. If this fails with `ENOTCONN`, the connection failed and we must then call `getsockopt` with `SO_ERROR` to fetch the pending error for the socket.
> 2. Call `read` with a length of 0. If the `read` fails, the `connect` failed and the `errno` from `read` indicates the reason for the connection failure. When a connection succeeds, `read` should return 0.
> 3. Call `connect` again. It should fail, and if the `error` is `EISCONN`, the socket is already connected and the first connection succeeded.

I tried the first one using `getpeername` and then fetch error only if the `getpeername` fails with `ENOTCONN`, and it worked for me, which is something like :

```
if(getpeername(ivSocketId, &addr, &addrlen) < 0)
{
  if (errno == ENOTCONN)
  {
    int sockErr = 0;
    socklen_t sockErrLen = sizeof(sockErr);
    if(getsockopt(ivSocketId, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR,
        &sockErr, &sockErrLen) < 0) 
    {
        // Handle errors, may be throw some exceptions
    }
    if(sockErr == 0)
    {
        //Handle Success scenario..
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle errors, may be throw some exceptions
    }
  }
  else
  {
      // Handle errors, may be throw some exceptions
  }
}
```